# how to configure netbeans for ruby on rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-plugins

how to configure netbeans for ruby on rails ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Update: Netbeans has [dropped](http://wiki.netbeans.org/RubySupport) support for ruby, unfortunately.

<strike>The netbeans documentation has sections on that matter:</strike>

- http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/ruby/setting-up.html
- http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/ruby/rails-quickstart.html

Answer (score 2):

Additional info.  On Apache NetBeans IDE 11.1 it will work!! (latest version as of 2019)

You need to get a copy of org-jdesktop-layout-RELEASE82.nbm and install it first.

I found it in this directory on the bits.netbeans.org release site:

http://bits.netbeans.org/nexus/content/groups/netbeans/org/netbeans/api/org-jdesktop-layout/RELEASE82/

After it is installed, follow the directions above from Marcos Riveros and you should be good to go.

Comment: In version 12 you also need to enable the NetBeans IDE 8.2 Update Center in the Plugin manager

Answer (score 1):

Google suggests:
http://wiki.netbeans.org/RubyOnRails
http://thoughtmining.blogspot.com/2007/03/installing-netbeans-with-rubyrails.html

Answer (score 1):

Currently, if you download Netbeans 7.0.1 (not the latest), you can use Tools->Plugins to open the Plugins window.  Click on "Available Plugins" and search for "Ruby on Rails".  Select it, and click install.

Unfortunately, the current version of Netbeans, 7.1, will not offer the Ruby on Rails plugin to you on the Available Plugins tab.  The following blog post gives some hope that it will eventually be there:

http://blog.enebo.com/2012/01/workaround-for-ruby-support-on-netbeans.html

In the meantime, use 7.0.1.

Answer (score 1):

Try install plugins manually:
1. Download and unzip the plugins for you netbeans http://plugins.netbeans.org/plugin/38549/ruby-and-rails
2. Click to tools->plugings->Downloaded, add path-to-pluging-downloaded.
Firts install the jar plugins (org-jruby-jruby.jar) and second install the pluging *.nbm.